# Electron Angular2(angular-cli) require internal module failed

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, angular-cli

I can't require internal module in my renderer process.
When i want to require internal node module or even electron, i got an error or undefined or empty object.

for example:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
console.log(fs) // empty object

import { spawn } from 'child_process'; // Can't find child_process module

import * as electron from 'electron' // fs.readFileSync is not a function
```

Here is my code:
**Electron**

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
let mainWin = null;
const loadURL = `http://localhost:4200`;
const createWindow = () => {
    mainWin = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 800
    });
    mainWin.loadURL(loadURL);
    mainWin.on('closed', () => {
        mainWin = null;
    });
}
app.on('ready', createWindow);
app.on('activate', () => {
    if (!mainWin) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

And renderer process Angular code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { readdirSync } from 'fs';
import { spawn } from 'child_process';
console.log(readdirSync);
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.styl']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}
}
```

What i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You are including server side modules in Angular which is for the browser.

Electron requires NodeJS the browser can't access the filesystem only the server can.

But Electron renders the index.html file using node so you can require electron via the index.html file

An example using parts of Electron in your Angular app.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular App</title>
  <base href="./">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">


</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>


  <script>
    window.electron = require("electron");
    window.ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer;
    window.electronRemote = require("electron").remote;
  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suppose it depends on your build system some are very restricting. I found this the most bug free way of working with electron using an angular-cli build.

Comment: What about the missing typings for it though?